# How can I create a layout in which agents do not overlap, so that each agent is clearly visible?

Tags: anylogic

for visual purposes, I would like my agents 'not to touch each other' during the simulation. I use standard networks and the spring-mass layout, but some agents overlap with each other.

Seems easy to me, but I could not find a solution...

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy as AnyLogic agents typically do not care about size and space (unless you use transporters and collision avoidance or pedestrians).

So you will have to code this yourself. But this is not trivial, depending on the problem.

Simplest solution: Write a check that periodically tries to see if any other agent's presentation is within your own presentation and if so, make yourself invisible (or smaller). But even that is not trivial.